# Periodically pointing api to refresh data. Battery?

Tags: android, api, battery

My app periodically refresh data by pointing the api. Right know this process is every 3 minutes. Thats mean that every 3 minutes app, points to api requests and calculating data. 
What is the best time value between refreshing points? Somewhere i ready that good is every 30 minutes.

I focusing right now on battery life and looking for the best solution.
Thanks.

Comment: You should accept an answer if you feel they answered your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exact answer for this question depends entirely on how important is "refresh" for your app to work stably.  I haven't checked the c2dm approach.
Few steps can be followed to improve performance and battery

1) Stop your periodic refresh when application is in background

2) Follow the design tips thats been given  [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html).

3) Its better to give user a choice regarding Refresh timer  with 10, 20 , 30 minutes as choice in your app settings  (optional).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google's C2DM to notify the device of new information instead of polling for it. Yes 3 minutes is too soon, use 30.

Comment: is it true that if I want to use C2DM user need first take a captcha challenge?

Comment: I don't recall, I think I didn't have to.